# PHP: Can I get the index in an array_map function?

Tags: php, arrays, loops, dictionary, iteration

I'm using a map in php like so:

```
function func($v) {
    return $v * 2;
}

$values = array(4, 6, 3);
$mapped = array_map(func, $values);
var_dump($mapped);
```

Is it possible to get the index of the value in the function?

Also - if I'm writing code that needs the index, should I be using a for loop instead of a map?

Answer (score 277, accepted):

Sure you can, with the help of [`array_keys():`](http://php.net/array_keys)

```
function func($v, $k)
{
    // key is now $k
    return $v * 2;
}

$values = array(4, 6, 3);
$mapped = array_map('func', $values, array_keys($values));
var_dump($mapped);
```

Comment: @Gordon yeah you can supply `array_map()` with an arbitrary number of arguments :)

Comment: This is a very risky approach as PHP does not guarantee that keys returned by `array_keys` will remain in same order as in original array. Thus you might end up mapping keys to wrong values. The safe approach is to use only `array_keys` as the second argument of `array_map` and then pass array to closure with `use` statement.

Comment: After doing this the mapped array lost its original indexes.

Comment: I frankly don't understand why PHP doesn't have a map function that supplies the key of each element as the second parameter of the callback.

Comment: @TimBezhashvyly Can you please flesh that out with a link to PHP's documentation? http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php Doesn't say anything about the order not being guaranteed.

Comment: @flu maybe you can use [array_walk](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-walk.php)

Comment: I agree that it's better not to use array_keys in this situation. Instead, we can get the indexes using: range(0, count($array)-1)

Comment: @DaveF for arrays like `$array = [3 => 'a', 4 => 'b'];` your solution will not work - see: https://3v4l.org/VqO3I

Comment: @flu [foreach](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php) can be used for that. Also you can throw in [yield](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php#control-structures.yield) if you dont want to create temporary array to return result.

Answer (score 15):

When mapping an anonymous function over an anonymous array, there is no way to access the keys:

```
array_map(
    function($val) use ($foo) { /* ... */ },
    array(key1 => val1,
          key2 => val2,
          /* ... */));
```

array_reduce doesn't get access to the keys either. array_walk can access keys, but the array is passed by reference, which requires a layer of indirection.

Some solutions are:

#### Array of pairs

This is bad, since we're changing the original array. Plus the boilerplate "array()" calls increase linearly with the length of the array:

```
array_map(
    function($pair) use ($foo) {
        list($key, $val) = $pair;
        /* ... */
    },
    array(array(key1, val1),
          array(key2, val2),
          /* ... */));
```

#### Temporary variable

We're acting on the original array, and the boilerplate is constant, but we can easily clobber an existing variable:

```
$i_hope_this_does_not_conflict = array(key1 => val1,
                                       key2 => val2,
                                       /* ... */);
array_map(
    function($key, $val) use ($foo) { /* ... */ },
    array_keys($i_hope_this_does_not_conflict),
    $i_hope_this_does_not_conflict);
unset($i_hope_this_does_not_conflict);
```

#### One-shot function

We can use function scope to prevent clobbering existing names, but have to add an extra layer of "use":

```
call_user_func(
    function($arr) use ($foo) {
        return array_map(function($key, $val) use ($foo) { /* ... */ },
                         array_keys($arr),
                         $arr);
    },
    array(key1 => val1,
          key2 => val2,
          /* ... */));
```

#### Multi-argument one-shot function

We define the function we're mapping in the original scope to prevent the "use" boilerplate):

```
call_user_func(
    function($f, $arr) {
        return array_map($f, array_keys($arr), $arr);
    },
    function($key, $val) use ($foo) { /* ... */ },
    array(key1 => val1,
          key2 => val2,
          /* ... */));
```

#### New function

The interesting thing to note is that our last one-shot function has a nice, generic signature and looks a lot like array_map. We might want to give this a name and re-use it:

```
function array_mapk($f, $arr) {
    return array_map($f, array_keys($arr), $arr);
}
```

Our application code then becomes:

```
array_mapk(
    function($key, $val) use ($foo) { /* ... */ },
    array(key1 => val1,
          key2 => val2,
          /* ... */));
```

#### Indirect Array Walk

When writing the above I'd ignored array_walk since it requires its argument to be passed by reference; however, I've since realised that it's easy to work around this using call_user_func. I think this is the best version so far:

```
call_user_func(
    'array_walk',
    array(key1 => val1,
          key2 => val2,
          /* ... */),
    function($val, $key) use ($foo) { /* ... */ });
```

Answer (score 13):

There is no way to access the index within the `array_map` callback. If you are working with sequential numeric indices, then an incrementing static variable could be used:

```php
$values = ["one", "two", "three"];

$mapped = array_map(function ($value) {
    static $i = 0;
    $result = "Index: $i, Value: $value";
    $i++;
    return $result;
}, $values);

print_r($mapped);
```

Resulting in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Index: 0, Value: one
    [1] => Index: 1, Value: two
    [2] => Index: 2, Value: three
)
```

When using this approach, it's important to use an [anonymous function](https://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.anonymous.php) as the callback and to never reuse that anonymous function to avoid referencing the same static variable outside of array_map.

Answer (score 6):

It's a bit of an old thread but as many of you, I'm using `array_keys`:

```php
array_map(function($id, $name) {
    print '<option value="'.$id.'">'.$name.'</option>';
}, array_keys($array), array_values($array));
```

---

Edit: Instead of `use` keyword, you can add two arrays in second parameter of your `arrray_map` function. I think no explications needed, the code is pretty simple.

Comment: `array_values($array)` can safely be `$array`.  If you aren't going to use `array_map()`'s `return`, then you probably should not be calling `array_map()`. It is most likely that `array_walk()` is better suited.

Answer (score 2):

Very simple:

Only array_map fuction: does not have index key!

```
 $params = [4,6,2,11,20];

 $data = array_map(function($v) { return ":id{$v}";}, $params);

 array (size=5)
  0 => string ':id4' (length=4)
  1 => string ':id6' (length=4)
  2 => string ':id2' (length=4)
  3 => string ':id11' (length=5)
  4 => string ':id20' (length=5)
```

Now, combine with array_keys:

```
$data = array_map(
    function($k) use ($params) { return ":id{$k}_${params[$k]}"; },
    array_keys($params)
 );

array (size=5)
  0 => string ':id0_4' (length=6)
  1 => string ':id1_6' (length=6)
  2 => string ':id2_2' (length=6)
  3 => string ':id3_11' (length=7)
  4 => string ':id4_20' (length=7)
```

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned by earlier posted answers, when keys and values are needed within the callback function's body, it is simplest to pass in the array of keys, then access the values for those keys via the original array.

With older versions that do not have arrow functions, use `use()` or `global` (I recommend the former) to allow access to the original array from within the callback.

With modern PHP (7.4+), use arrow function syntax. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/KIWoo))

```
$values = [4, 6, 3];
var_export(
    array_map(
        fn($k) => "$k: " . $values[$k] * 2,
        array_keys($values)
    )
);
```

---

There is also no shame in using a `foreach()` and modifying the values by reference. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/SrWAC))

```
$values = [4, 6, 3];
foreach ($values as $k => &$v) {
    $v = "$k: " . $v * 2;
}
var_export($values);
```

Answer (score 2):

One simple line that I use to build PDO queries.  Works well.  Uses anonymous function in this case.

```
$values = array(4, 6, 3);
$mapped = array_map(function($v,$i) {return $v*2;}, $values, range(0,count($values)-1));
var_dump($mapped);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own map function using `foreach`:

```
<?php

function myCallback($key, $val)
{
    var_dump("myCallback - key: $key, val: $val");
    return $val * 2;
}

function foreachMap($callback, $givenArray) {
    $result = [];
    foreach ($givenArray as $key=>$val) {
        $result[$key] = $callback($key, $val);
    }
    return $result;
}

$values = array(4, 6, 3);
$mapped = foreachMap('myCallback', $values);
var_dump($mapped);
```

try: https://3v4l.org/pmFlB

Answer (score 0):

For a fast and open solution (without doubling array using array_keys and similar):

```
/**
 * Array map alternative to work with values and keys of single array.
 *
 * Callable receives $value and $index of $sourceArray as arguments
 * If keys are not preserved via $preserveKeys - $keyCallback can be used to determinate key
 *
 * @param array $sourceArray
 * @param callable|null $valueCallback
 * @param callable|null $keyCallback
 * @param bool $preserveKeys
 * @return array
 */
function array_map_indexed(
    array $sourceArray,
    ?callable $valueCallback = null,
    ?callable $keyCallback = null,
    bool $preserveKeys = true
): array {
    $newArray = [];

    foreach ($sourceArray as $key => $value) {
        if ($preserveKeys) {
            $newArray[$keyCallback ? $keyCallback($value, $key) : $key] = $valueCallback
                ? $valueCallback($value, $key)
                : $value;
        } else {
            $newArray[] = $valueCallback
                ? $valueCallback($value, $key)
                : $value;
        }
    }

    return $newArray;
}
```

Usage examples:

```
$result = array_map_indexed(
    [
        'a' => 'aValue',
        'b' => 'bValue',
    ],
    function($value, $index) {
        return [$value, $index];
    },
);
//Array ( [a] => Array ( [0] => aValue [1] => a ) [b] => Array ( [0] => bValue [1] => b ) )

$result = array_map_indexed(
    [
        'a' => 'aValue',
        'b' => 'bValue',
    ],
    function($value, $index) {
        return $index.$value;
    },
    null,
    false
);
//Array ( [0] => aaValue [1] => bbValue )

$result = array_map_indexed(
    [
        'a' => 'aValue',
        'b' => 'bValue',
    ],
    null,
    function($value, $index) {
        return $value === 'aValue' ? 'specificKey' : $index;
    },
);
//Array ( [specificKey] => aValue [b] => bValue )
```

Answer (score 0):

You can generate your own index to be used with array_map:

```
function func($v, $index) {
  return $v * 2;
}

$values = array(4, 6, 3);
$valuesIndex = range(0, count($values) - 1);
$mapped = array_map(func, $values, $valuesIndex);
var_dump($mapped);
```

As shown above, you may securely create an array of numbers from 0 to the length of your array, same as a index.
Put this second array in the array_map and use it values as index in your function.

Comment: I don't see where the `func` constant is defined.  You did not test this code.  Please test your snippets on 3v4l.org before posting in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Calling two functions (`range(0, count($values) - 1)`) to generate data that is already generated is not a good idea.  Just access what is already available with `array_keys()`.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the array_keys() function to get the keys of an array, and then loop through those keys using a foreach loop.

```php
$keys = array_keys($array);
foreach($keys as $key){
   // do something with $key
}
```

Comment: You're right, but this is not exactly what the OP asks (the question is about `array_map`)