# how to access the current index in array_reduce?

Tags: php

Having read this [SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5868457/php-can-i-get-the-index-in-an-array-map-function/5868491#5868491), In PHP I am aware that you can get the `index` under iteration with `array_map` as such:

```
array_map(function($item, $index) { ... }, $items, array_keys($items));
```

How can I get the an `$index` available to me when I use `array_reduce`? I have tried:

```
array_reduce($items, array_keys($items), function($acc, $item, $index) { ... }, array());

array_reduce($items, function($acc, $item, $index) { ... }, array(), array_keys($items));
```

But I still can't seem to get `$index` in an `array_reduce`. Has anyone successfully done this before?

**EDIT**

Here's some context as to why I am asking this question.

I do not want to use `foreach` because I would have to mutate an array outside of the `foreach` in order to create my collection. I would prefer to avoid mutation.

Other languages allow one to use `reduce` and get access to the current index like in [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) and [Ruby](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42672108/2524631). I was hoping to get the same feature in PHP. Oh well! Looks like I'm going to have to use a `foreach` to create my array while also having the current index under iteration.

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You reduce the values in the array, why would you need the keys?

Comment: Not really sure what the question is. The callback signature is `callback ( mixed $carry , mixed $item ) : mixed` as [documentation](http://php.net/array_reduce) says. This is it.

Comment: Have you tried to read the [documentation of `array_reduce()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)? You don't get any keys in the callback.

Comment: @Dharman what about my question does not make sense? If I am iterating over an array using a reduce function then at any given loop / iteration I want to know the current index. What is confusing about what I want? The same feature I am asking for is in `array_map`.

Comment: The confusing part is that we already have something to do that: `foreach($arr as $k => $v)`

Comment: @robskrob Why do you need the index? Sounds like an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @axiac I am not proposing a solution. What I have tried is not working. That's why I am asking for help. I am pretty sure in other languages like Ruby or Javascript I can use their reduce functions and get the current index of the loop in the reduce function.

Comment: @Dharman because I strongly dislike using `foreach` to mutate an array.

Comment: @robskrob Why? `foreach` is literally _for_ iterating through an array.

Comment: I really doubt that you would be able to find a "reduce" function in other languages which gives you the index.

Comment: @axiac ok then the answer is, this is not possible.

Comment: @Dharman you can in Javascript, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce

Comment: @axiac you can get the current index in reduce functions of other languages (Ruby, Javascript). Moreover, in PHP you can get the current index with `array_map`. Looks like you can't do this in PHP -- which is unfortunate.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php#118254

Comment: As a workaround you can apply `array_reduce()` to the keys of the array (`array_keys()`) and use the keys to access the values. As long as you don't explain why do you need it, the question still doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: It may be useful to create your solution using foreach, then ask on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) to see if there is a more elegant way to do it.

Answer (score 10):

I just had same issue. It's pretty simple to solve.

```
$i = 0;
$p = array_reduce($array, function($output, $item) use (&$i) {
   // use $i
   // do something with $item and/or $output
   $i++; // increment $i
   return $output;
}, $initial);
```

`&$i` pass `$i` as reference and grants it will be updated.

Comment: This works, but mutating state outside of the callback is brittle, inelegant and exactly the problem we're trying to avoid with functions like `array_reduce`. Better to just use `foreach` with index than trying to shoehorn `array_reduce` into something it's not.

Comment: It's a nice hack but it's too bad that PHP doesn't include a better version, because it will not work for associative arrays or arrays with empty indexes (such as arrays passed in `array_unique`)

Answer (score 3):

Arrays in PHP are peculiar things: they can be used as lists, queues, dictionaries, sets, ordered dictionaries, and all sorts of other multi-valued structures. However, most functions are written with one or two of those structures in mind.

In the case of `array_reduce`, the array is treated as a *list* - an ordered collection of items. As such, the *keys* of the array are not handed to the callback. This makes sense for common cases, like calculating a total, or an average, etc.

There are undoubtedly cases where you want to instead reduce an ordered dictionary of key-value pairs; unfortunately, PHP does not provide a function for that.

On the other hand, there are two related functions which might be usable instead:

- `array_map`, which runs the callback on each element and produces a new array with one item of output for item of input
- `array_walk`, which runs the callback on each element and ignores the result, but which can take a third parameter by reference where side-effects can be accumulated

All three functions can also trivially be implemented with a `foreach` loop, so you could write your own `reduce` function something like this (*untested*):

```
function array_reduce_assoc(array $array, callable $callback, $initial=null) {
    $carry = $initial;
    foreach ( $array as $key => $value ) {
        $carry = $callback($carry, $key, $value);
    }
    return $carry;
}
```

Comment: `array_reduce_assoc` should return `$carry`

Comment: @parse So it should! Fixed.

Answer (score 3):

```
<?php
$data = ['one', 'two', 'three'];

$result = array_reduce($data, function($carry, $item){
    $carry['out'] .= $carry['i'] . ') '. $item . '; ';
    $carry['i']++;
    return $carry;
}, ['out' => '', 'i' => 1] )['out'];

echo $result; // 1) one; 2) two; 3) three;
```

Comment: This worked perfectly for me, as I didn't need to add the `['out']` to the end, since I am already doing array (associative) destructuring on the result!

Answer (score 1):

You already know you how to get the index in `array_map`, so you could use that to reduce instead if you like. Just `use` a reference to the "carry" variable in the callback.

```
$example = ['a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3];

array_map(function($key, $value) use (&$reduced) {
    $reduced .= "$key$value";  // for example
}, array_keys($example), $example);

echo $reduced;  //a1b2c3
```

I'm not sure I see the advantage of this over foreach, but it's another possible way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

This is similar to [another answer](//stackoverflow.com/questions/54258642/-/54259037), but differs on a couple of points.

First, the other answer provides an example, but not a complete one. Also the
other answer defines the callback arguments as `$carry, $key, $value`. I feel
that `$carry, $value, $key` would be better, as it would match
[JavaScript reduce](//developer.mozilla.org/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

It would also keep the order of PHP’s own [array_reduce](//php.net/function.array-reduce), while just adding
an extra argument. For my example I am implementing [array_flip](//php.net/function.array-flip), just to
demonstrate what is possible:

```
<?php
$a = ['May', 'June'];
$m = [];

$f = function ($m_acc, $s_cur, $n_idx) {
   return $m_acc + [$s_cur => $n_idx];
};

foreach ($a as $n => $s) {
   $m = $f($m, $s, $n);
}

print_r($m);
```

Answer (score -1):

What you're aware about the getting index in `array_reduce` doesn't exist. [Check documentation.](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-reduce.php)

The question is **why**?

Look, reduce is being used for the purpose of getting down to one single value, it's aggregation. You have initial value, and next value, show your reduce strategy. There is no point in knowing current item index.

In some other languages, they might provide current index, but not for this `array_reduce` in PHP. It's language and function designed, there are some constraints in implementation.

But it doesn't mean you can't have it. You can have it, but not through callback!

```
$i = 0;
$data = [1, 2, 3, 4];

// (1) 
$result = array_reduce($data, function ($c, $i) { return $c + $i; }, 0);

// (2)
array_reduce($data, function ($c, $i) { echo "$i\n"; $i++; return $c + $i; }, 0);
```

The thing is, the function is designed to do this. Or you're trying to use a wrong function. Some other functions might be what you're looking for.

Or you can write a function that do it, too :)

Comment: In my original question I provided some context as to why. Hope that sheds some light on why I am asking the question.

Comment: Maybe you're asking for a wrong function in PHP to help your problems in "creating collection". I suggest to ask that "creating collection" you're troubling with, so PHP developers can suggest a proper and elegant solution.